# How to set session timeout or expired token in angular?

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular-directive

Currently i am working on angular,i want to set automatic logout or want to make automatic session expired in angular help for this?

authguard.guard.ts

```
export class AuthguardGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor (private user : SupportService,private router : Router) {}
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
   if(localStorage.getItem('username')){  
      return true;
   }else{
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

login-form.component.ts

```
export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit {

userObj : User = new User();
constructor(private router : Router, private user : SupportService, private route : ActivatedRoute) { }
loginUser(e){
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('username',this.userObj.username);
formData.append('password', this.userObj.password);
this.user.getUserPass(formData).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    if(data != undefined && data.payload != undefined && data.status == 1){
      e.preventDefault();
      this.router.navigate(['/base/dashboard']);    
      localStorage.setItem('userid',data.payload[0].userid);
      localStorage.setItem('username',data.payload[0].username);
    }else{
      alert('Please Enter Valid UserName OR Password');
     }    
    }  
   )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can used as  cookies in angular for the invalid token  after destroy  cookie and check then if cookie data  not have this condition also removed as token and get after new token

Comment: i tried this way but not found right way to do can you help me in my code ?

Comment: John ,you can also used as cron service so manage as service which set a time and this cron call whenever  as you set a time

Comment: or used another way of solve like you can manage setTimeOut()
 setTimeout(function(){
  localStorage.removeKey('token');
},10000000)


here you can manage time as  depend when you will destroy  as session